# How to set the output bindings for name and location in an Azure function using python?

Tags: python-3.x, azure-functions, azure-storage

I can't quite seem to get the output bindings to enable a file to be saved to blob storage. I have created an Azure Function using Python, that uses a CosmosDB Change Feed trigger. I need to save that document to blob storage.
I've set-up the function.json file as follows:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "type": "cosmosDBTrigger",
      "name": "documents",
      "direction": "in",
      "leaseCollectionName": "leases",
      "connectionStringSetting": "cosmos_dev",
      "databaseName": "MyDatabase",
      "collectionName": "MyCollection",
      "createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists": "true"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "raw/changefeedOutput/{blobname}",
      "connection": "blobStorageConnection"
    }
  ]
}
```

So the trigger will get a documents like the following:

```
{ "id": "documentId-12345",
  other sections here
  "entity": "customer"
}
```

In the **init**.py file I have the base code of

```py
def main(documents: func.DocumentList) -> func.Document:
        logging.info(f"CosmosDB trigger executed!")
        for doc in documents:
                blobName = doc['id'] + '.json'
                blobFolder= doc['entity'] 
                blobData = doc.to_json()
```

I think i need to add in the def something like 'outputBlob: func.Out' but unsure how to proceed

Looking at the examples on github

https://github.com/yokawasa/azure-functions-python-samples/tree/master/v2functions/blob-trigger-watermark-blob-out-binding

it look like i have to 
outputBlob.set(something)
So i'm looking for how to set up the def part and send the blob to the location that i've set from the data in the cosmosdb document.

I have tried the following:

```
def main(documents: func.DocumentList, outputBlob: func.Out[str] ) -> func.Document:
        logging.info(f"CosmosDB trigger executed!")
        for doc in documents:
                blobName = doc['id'] + '.json'
                outputBlob.set(blobName)
```

and get the result:

```
CosmosDB trigger executed!
Executed 'Functions.CosmosTrigger_py' (Failed, Id=XXXXX)
System.Private.CoreLib: Exception while executing function: Functions.CosmosTrigger_py. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: No value for named parameter 'blobname'.
```

I could just call the connection stuff from the os.enviro, and get the connection string that way, I think and use the standard create_blob_from_text, with location, name and blob data,

block_blob_service.create_blob_from_text(blobLocation, blobName, formattedBlob)

Any pointers would be great

Comment: What are the errors/issues you're getting ?

Comment: The main issue is i'm not sure how to send the path to the binding and save the blob to the location

Comment: have you tried something ?

Comment: @Thomas, I have updated the post with what I have tried to do, based on the git hub examples here https://gist.github.com/csiebler/28ef684f3bcd94a524e4c131df9c0750